# Read encoded url

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain why the first code doesn't work and the second does. The only difference is that the string is split in a different place.

Doesn't work:

```js
var text = '{"data":[' +
  '{"name": "Gersch\u00e4ftsf\u00f' +
  'chrer"}' +
  ']}';
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<p id="test"></p>
```

This works fine:

```js
var text = '{"data":[' +
  '{"name": "Gersch\u00e4ftsf\u00fc' +
  'hrer"}' +
  ']}';
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<p id="test"></p>
```

I get it working if I pass the character `ü` not as `\u00fc` but as `%C3%BC`

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you're splitting the string in the middle of a Unicode escape sequence. When you use the `+` operator with strings, you concatenate them, but Unicode escape sequences are resolved before concatenation.

So, in your first code, it's trying to resolve the sequence `\u00f`, which is impossible because Unicode escape sequences need to be four characters long.

In your second code, you use the full sequence `\u00fc` which is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Escape sequences (such as `\u00fc`) are converted to characters when the string literal is parsed (i.e. converted from source code to a string).

If you put half of an escape sequence in one string literal and half in another string literal (and then attempt to join the two parts together with the `+` operator) then the escape sequence is incomplete at the time JavaScript tries to convert it into a character.

Comment: and is there any way to avoid this?
I get a JSON object in my application, which is passed in lines of 256 characters. So sometimes it happens that an encoded character has split in two rows.
How can I turn this into one string? of can I try to escape it a second time ?

Comment: I'm not going to try to solve that problem based on a relatively vague description of what your code does. Try asking a new question about passing the JSON from wherever you are getting it from to JavaScript (making sure to include a [mcve] and to follow the rest of the advice in [ask]).

Answer (score 1):

The console error is telling you exactly the problem:

> Invalid Unicode escape sequence

This is an invalid unicode character:

```
\u00f
```

But this one is valid:

```
\u00fc
```

The rest of the string, such as how you split it, is irrelevant.  The syntax of the unicode character must be correct within the string literal that uses it.  This literal is invalid:

```
'{"name": "Gersch\u00e4ftsf\u00f'
```

So any JavaScript code which tries to *use* this literal will fail because of that invalid unicode syntax.  It doesn't matter if that code was going to try to append another string literal to this one, since this string literal is broken it can't be used for that or any other purpose.

Just as in the working version, split the string in such a way that each individual string literal is a valid string literal.